# xxd without line number but keep character encoding

Tags: vim, xxd

I know that using `-p` can output in plain hexdump style, but I want to keep the character encoding in the righthand column and separation of the output. Does `xxp` have any options to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't but you can use additional tools:

```
xxd file | cut -d' ' -f 2-
```

Use [`cut`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/cut) to split by spaces and skip the 1st field.

Comment: A solution with `sed` : `xxd ~/101/libft/libft.a | sed 's/\ \ .*//;s/^.*:\ //;s/\ .*//'`. Delete last column (it contains special characters messing up the next steps) (from 'two spaces' till end of line), then delete the first column (everything until the first character following a ':'), then delete all but the original second column (delete from the first space until the end)